# Postgresql: Repeat query many times with different parameters - cleaner method than unions?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to repeat the same query using different parameters. I can write this with several union statements but am hoping there is a way to write a function for cleaner code. Thanks!

The query that I need to repeat is:

```
SELECT
  'marker_1'       AS marker,
  b.marker_1       AS results,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id) AS number_of_results,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id) * 100 / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id))
  OVER ()         AS percentage
FROM main_table a
  JOIN main_table_marker_results b ON b.key_id = a.id
WHERE a.is_marker = 'true'
GROUP BY marker, marker_1
UNION
SELECT
  'marker_xyz'       AS marker,
  b.marker_xyz       AS results,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id) AS number_of_results,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id) * 100 / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id))
  OVER ()         AS percentage
FROM main_table a
  JOIN main_table_marker_results b ON b.key_id = a.id
WHERE a.is_marker_xyz = 'true'
GROUP BY marker, marker_xyz
```

I need to do this for about 20 different markers. Does anyone know any way to loop this query with different parameters? The variables that would change are marker and results. There are 20 different markers, all with varying names (represented by 'marker_1' in this query) that have their own column. Contained in the column is the result for that marker, so "result" from this query could be {positive, negative, undetermined}.

The final output should look like:

```
marker      result         number_of_results   percentage
marker_1    positive        350                 49.5
marker_1    negative        48                  6.8
marker_1    undetermined    309                 43.7
marker_xyz  positive        500                 80.0
marker_xyz  negative        25                  4.00
marker_xyz  undetermined    100                 16.00
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Your "marker" is a constant value, shouldn't that be part of the table somehow? If you replace the constant with another constant, you get exactly the same values over and over again.

Comment: I've made some updates to hopefully clarify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but I think this should achieve what you want:

```
SELECT x.marker,
       x.result,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id) AS number_of_results,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id) * 100 / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id))
       OVER ()         AS percentage
FROM main_table a
  JOIN main_table_marker_results b ON b.key_id = a.id
  JOIN LATERAL (
    values 
     ('{"is_marker_1": true}'::jsonb, 'marker_1', marker_1), 
     ('{"is_marker_2": true}'::jsonb, 'marker_2', marker_2),
     ('{"is_marker_xyz": true}'::jsonb, 'marker_xyz', marker_xyz)
  ) as x(condition, marker, result) ON to_jsonb(a) @> condition
GROUP BY x.marker, x.result;
```

Note that the key in the JSONB constant must match exactly the column name in your table, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! However, I realize I specified the is_marker_1 incorrectly. This field is actually is_marker and will be = true if there are results for any of the tested markers. Therefore the '{"is_marker_1":true}'::jsonb is not required as we can just specify where is_marker = true for the whole query. How would we edit this to specify x.marker and x.result only?

Comment: Got it, I just joined on true. Thank you!!